# OpenVPN server doesn't redirect to other client

Tags: openvpn

I can ping the server (192.168.10.1) but i cant ping the other client (192.168.1.242).

This problem solves via command.

```
sudo route -n add -net 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.10.1
```

However it is annoying to do it every time I connect to VPN.

What command should I add to open VPN file to automatically add the network?

Current certificate file is shown below.

```
    client
    proto udp
    remote ip port
    dev tun
    resolv-retry infinite
    nobind
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    remote-cert-tls server
    verify-x509-name 
    auth SHA256
    auth-nocache
    cipher 
    tls-client
    tls-version-min 
    tls-cipher 
    setenv opt block-outside-dns
    verb 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up routing according to https://openvpn.net/community-resources/setting-up-routing/.

Comment: I tried to use this command route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.3.0.1 as it is said in the openvpn settings for routing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on your client, then you need to add the network and gateway to your config file as per the description:

> route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric]

Which in your case would be something like this

> route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1

*(brackets are optional, so skip [metric])*

If you would like all clients to have the route, then use `push "route <same format as above>"` in your server configuration instead.